# Ordering a list in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am looking to order my list from person with highest "leaguePoints" to lowest in php simplest way, my code goes to riot servers url gets the data from the url using a api and username of the person im searching.
Thanks in advance.

Prints out like this:

TRC Broxah | 713LP | 229Wins | 145Losses

v Cabo | 440LP | 131Wins | 87Losses

Melty Wakz | 459LP | 65Wins | 33Losses

MLG Glebo HLTV | 450LP | 182Wins | 150Losses

Huikee Masa | 444LP | 287Wins | 250Losses

AtraX Belze | 648LP | 261Wins | 204Losses

Every1Wants2Rule | 557LP | 68Wins | 33Losses

EL Steeve | 742LP | 109Wins | 69Losses

łÍÎÌÍIIIIIIIlla | 1063LP | 255Wins | 112Losses

0C0 | 756LP | 182Wins | 116Losses

UOL Vizicsacsi | 474LP | 106Wins | 88Losses

Melty Tioo | 492LP | 135Wins | 106Losses

SLEEPlNG | 418LP | 211Wins | 192Losses

Trashyyy | 480LP | 97Wins | 67Losses

```
<?php
$apiKey = 'RIOT API';
$summonerName = 'raget deathdex';
$new = rawurlencode($summonerName);

$news = str_replace(' ', '', $summonerName);
$str = strtolower($news);



// get the basic summoner info
$result = file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' . $new . '?api_key=' . $apiKey);
$summoner = json_decode($result)->$str;
$id = $summoner->id;
// var_dump($summoner);
?>  








<?php
$challengerleaguerankingList = file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/challenger?type=RANKED_SOLO_5x5&api_key=e9044828-20e3-46cc-9eb5-545949299803');

$getchallengerleaguerankingList = json_decode($challengerleaguerankingList);

?>
```

**this is the part of the code that i need to be ordered by highest to lowest leaguepoints:**

```
<?php foreach($getchallengerleaguerankingList->entries as $statSummaryz){


print '<p><b>' .$statSummaryz->playerOrTeamName. '</b> | <font color="blue">' .$statSummaryz->leaguePoints. '</font>LP | <font color="green">' .$statSummaryz->wins. '</font>Wins | <font color="red">' .$statSummaryz->losses.'Losses </font></p>';

}array_multisort($statSummaryz->leaguePoints, SORT_DESC, $statSummaryz);
?>
```

Comment: Can you display the API's response ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you would use the [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

**Example:**

```
$entries = $getchallengerleaguerankingList->entries;
usort($entries, function($a,$b){
    return $a->leaguePoints-$b->leaguePoints;
});
foreach($entries as $statSummaryz){
    print '<p><b>' .$statSummaryz->playerOrTeamName. '</b> | <font color="blue">' .$statSummaryz->leaguePoints. '</font>LP | <font color="green">' .$statSummaryz->wins. '</font>Wins | <font color="red">' .$statSummaryz->losses.'Losses </font></p>';
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspire you to this code (I've go to the [documentation of uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) and little changing for you). Uasort can sort an array with function callback.

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ((int)$a < (int)$b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$array = array('2LP','1LP');
var_dump($array);



Show :
     : Array
(
    [0] => 2LP
    [1] => 1LP
)

uasort($array, 'cmp');
var_dump($array);

Show :
    : Array
    (
        [1] => 1LP
        [0] => 2LP
    )
```

Note the `(int)` cast for keep the number before "LP" so 1LP is interpreted like 1.

You can use that for sort your array (in your case, it's an object) by the number of LP

Good luck, ask if you can't do that